# How to maintain separate form keys in PageView multiple pages?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-pageview

PageView.builder creates indexed pages when passed with length parameter.

I have multiple pages in Pageview. Each page has its own form. However the form on each page has same Widget tree.
I have used form key using Form widget. Now when I edits a field in the form, it gets updated for all the pages available.

How can we prevent this behaviour, making possible only that it updates the current page fields?

Answer (score 0):

Include the new form key for all the pages in your modal class or response class.

Like This :

```
Class Foo {
... Other Fields
GlobalKey<FormState> key;
// Your From Json Method
Foo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
//Initialize the key here!!
key = GlobalKey<FormState>();
}
}
```

> Use this key same as how you use your other data in your Page Views!